# What could be the reason for my car not starting

Tags: battery, chevrolet, captiva

I have a 2014 Chevy Captiva. The engine was just replaced last year. My car won't start. I turn the key and can hear one click and then nothing. The lights on the dash all come on, the radio works, the back up sensor turns on when put into reverse, I can roll the windows up and down. It just won't turn over. It shows my battery is at 11.8 volts. Is the battery just dying or could it be something else

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think I'd have the starter checked to ensure it is working correctly. Depending on how loud the "click" is, your description is leading me to believe the starter might be bad.

Comment: Average (medium to premium priced) battery life is around 5 years, longer in temperate climates, shorter in desert climates. All car batteries should exhibit 12.5v before starting, relying on the drive belt and alternator to recharge after every start. Battery cables must be free of corrosion with secure connections. If in doubt about your battery, remove it for testing at your favorite auto store selling car batteries as they should have free battery testing. Lights and radio are not battery tests. Starters demand a good battery and cables to draw anywhere from 50-200 amps of current.